# Breeze JS "In" Clause or Http POST for Queries

Tags: breeze

I am wondering what the best way is to perform an in clause query with breeze. I've used a series of 'column = blah1 or column = blah2', etc. I've also made a named server method that accepts an array of parameters, and called it using the withParameters syntax. The problem I'm facing is when the list gets long, I can bump up against the http GET querystring limit.

Is there a better way to perform "in" clause queries with breeze, and what is the best way to deal with long lists of terms when performing these queries (is http POST possible when querying?)

Thanks for your time,
Mathias

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question.  We are looking at providing a simplified query mechanism that uses POST instead of GET for exactly these reasons.  This will probably be available within the next release or two.